# How to write a program to estimate the sine function as a Taylor series in C?

Tags: c, trigonometry, taylor-series

I'm new to programming and I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. If there is any way that someone could help me understand what is wrong with my program I would really appreciate it. I have already been working on this problem for two hours and I know I am making it harder than it needs to be. This is my new code. my new output is 0.000000476837158.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main() {
         double x, sinx, z, factorial, term;
         int j, n, i;
         x=0.5;
         n=10;
         i=0;
         z=sin(0.5);
         for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
                      factorial = 1;
                      for(j=2*i +1; j<=i; j++)
                      {
                               factorial = factorial * j;
                               }
                      term=(pow(-1,i)*pow(x,2*i+1))/(factorial);
                      sinx=term++;
                      i=i++;
                                   }
                      printf("sin(0.5) is approximately %.15lf\n", sinx);
                      printf("sin(0.5) by default function is %.15lf\n", z);
                      system("pause");
                      return 0;
                      }
```

Comment: what output do you actually get?

Comment: It won' generate any output, just a blank screen

Comment: You calculate `factorial` (incorrectly) and then never use it.

Comment: Do not use Taylor coefficients to build a uniformly precise approximation (but you are not there yet). http://lolengine.net/blog/2011/12/21/better-function-approximations

Comment: I have to use TAylor coefficients for the problem

Comment: You really should try something easier first.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think your second for loop is doing anything. Unless 2*i wraps around, j will never be less than i.

Comment: For debugging, recommend using `%.15le`, then you can see small values better.

Answer (score 1):

This loop doesn't make sense.

```
 for(j=0; j<=i; j++){
     factorial=2*j+1;
     }
```

It doesn't do anything different than

```
factorial = 2*i+1;
```

If you wanted to calculate a factorial(like `i!`) than I'd do the following

```
// initialize `factorial`
factorial = 1;
for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
{
    //multiply `factorial` by `j`.  
    factorial = factorial * j;
}
```

---

you keep using `sinx` and `term`, but they're never initialized.  This means that they'll contain garbage values.

---

`i++` incriments on it's own, you shouldn't have to use any extra assignment operators.

change

```
i=i++;
```

to simply

```
i++;
```

or better yet, use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop

```
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
```

Comment: I entered the factorial like you suggested @Sam I am I also removed the first ocurrence of sinx=sinx+term. But I still don't get any output whatsoever.

Comment: SO I changed my while loop to a for loop as suggested and I changed my for loop containing the j value from j=0 which gave me an output of 1.#INF000000 , then made j=1 which gave 0.000000000000131

Answer (score 0):

The first occurrence of this statement

```
     sinx=sinx+term;
```

will be one of your problems since neither of the variables on the *rhs* of the assignment has been initialised when you first use them.  Subsequent executions of the same line, inside the loop, will propagate the junk value of `sinx` throughout the computation.

I expect there are other problems too but haven't examined the code very closely.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused on how to initialize these variables then

Answer (score 0):

Your i<sup>th</sup> term is -1<sup>i</sup> x<sup>2i+1</sup>/i, which grows *fast*. You should have printed out the first couple of terms to discover the problem.

(There are other problems too, like `i=i++;`, but they can wait.)

Comment: `i=i++;` can wait? In a question tagged “C”?!

Comment: Thsi is my new source code after adressing some of the problems you guys corrected me on: